# Cannot import IOKit on Xcode 9 Beta 2 or Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to import IOKit in my project but autocompletion doesn't detect the IOKit. I have tried different steps from stack overflow and github too. But none of them seems to work. I have IOKit.framework in my Framework folder.

More than that, I did a fresh re-install of Xcode9 Beta 2 also but the problem is same:

[image: It doesn't detect the module]

Also I tried to add it through Linked Frameworks and Libraries. But the problem is same:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

I also added Framework search paths to /Users/administrator/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks

Then I get alot of errors like Could not build module "IOSurface" and many more.

Can anybody give any idea what is happening here.

Comment: IIRC, IOKit is not a public framework for iOS apps.  Thus unsupported by Apple.

Comment: This [blog entry](http://www.ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/iokit-an-introduction/) seems to agree that iOS apps created with IOKit will be rejected.

Comment: Yes I know that app will be rejected. But i want to try something from there. Can you please help me